# Regular open sets and set differences

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $T$ is a metric space. A subset $R$ of $T$ is called [*regular open*](https://planetmath.org/regularopenset) if the interior of the closure of $R$ is equal to $R$ itself:

$$ R = \text{int}(\text{cl}(R)).$$

Suppose $R$ and $S$ are two (non empty) regular open sets with $S \subset R$ (strict inclusion). Is it then necessarily the case that

$$ \text{cl}( R \setminus S) = \text{cl}( \text{cl}(R ) \setminus \text{cl} (S) )?$$

(I worked out this was false in general, my question is whether being regularly open is the right property to ensure it's true)

Comment: You haven't been around for a few years, and in the meantime the link to PlanetMath you cited has died. Fortunately they converted that PDF to an HTML based "topic page", and I've replaced the link.  Feel free to roll back my edit if you feel I have inadvertently changed the meaning of your Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, even for a topological space $T$.

Proof of $\supset$. Let $R$ and $S$ be *any* subsets of $T$. Let $x\in \text{cl}( (\text{cl } R) \setminus \text{cl } S )$ be an arbitrarily point and $U$ be an arbitrary open neighborhood of the point $x$. Then there exists a point $x’\in U\cap ((\text{cl }R) \setminus \text{cl } S)$. A set $V=U\setminus \text{cl } S$ is a neighborhood of the point $x’$. Since $x’\in \text{cl }R$, there exists a point $x’’\in R\cap V\subseteq R\setminus \text{cl } S $. Thus $x\in \text{cl}(R\setminus \text{cl } S )\subseteq \text{cl}(R\setminus S)$.

Proof of $\subset$. Let $R$ be an open and $S$ be a canonically open subsets of $T$.
Let $x\in \text{cl}( R \setminus S)$ be an arbitrarily point and $U$ be an arbitrary open neighborhood of the point $x$. Then there exists a point $x’\in U\cap (R \setminus S)$.
Since the set $R$ is open, $V=U\cap R$ is an open neighborhood of the point $x'$. If the set $S$ is dense in $V$ then $x'\in V\subseteq\text{int cl } S=S$, a contradiction. Therefore there exists a point $x''\in V\setminus\text{cl } S\subseteq R\setminus\text{cl } S$. Thus  $x\in \text{cl}(R\setminus \text{cl } S)\subseteq \text{cl}((\text{cl }R)\setminus (\text{cl } S))$.